# Getting symbols with Lark parsing

Tags: python, parsing

I'm trying to parse a little pseudo-code I'm writing and having some trouble getting values for symbols.  It parses successfully, but it won't return a value the same as it would with "regular" characters.  Here's an example:

```
>>> from lark import Lark
>>> parser = Lark('operator: "<" | ">" | "=" | ">=" | "<=" | "!="', start="operator")
>>> parsed = parser.parse(">")
>>> parsed
Tree(operator, [])
>>> parsed.data
'operator'
>>> parsed.value
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Tree' object has no attribute 'value'
```

Why wouldn't there be a value?  Is there another way to get the exact operator that was used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Author of Lark here. Mike's answer is accurate, but a better way to get the same result is by using the "!" prefix on the rule:

```
>>> from lark import Lark
>>> parser = Lark('!operator: "<" | ">" | "=" | ">=" | "<=" | "!="', start="operator")
>>> parser.parse(">")
Tree(operator, [Token(__MORETHAN, '>')])
```

Answer (score 3):

It appears that by default it removes "tokens"(or what it considered 'punctuation' marks.  Luckily, there is an option to change that behavior called `keep_all_tokens`.

Here's an example with that option:

```
>>> from lark import Lark
>>> parser = Lark('operator: "<" | ">" | "=" | ">=" | "<=" | "!="', start="operator", keep_all_tokens=True)
>>> parsed = parser.parse(">")
>>> parsed
Tree(operator, [Token(__MORETHAN, '>')])
>>> parsed.children[0].value
'>'
```