# Lark: parsing special characters

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, context-free-grammar, lark-parser

I'm starting with `Lark` and got stuck on an issue with parsing special characters.

I have expressions given by a grammar. For example, these are valid expressions: `Car{_}`, `Apple3{3+}`, `Dog{a_7}`, `r2d2{A3*}`, `A{+}`... More formally, they have form: `name{feature}` where

- `name: CNAME`
- `feature: (DIGIT|LETTER|"+"|"-"|"*"|"_")+`

The definition of constants can be found [here](https://github.com/lark-parser/lark/blob/master/lark/grammars/common.lark).

The problem is that the special characters are not present in produced tree (see example below). I have seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46008954/7388106), but it did not help me. I tried to place `!` before special characters, escaping them. I also enabled keep_all_tokens, but this is not desired because then characters `{` and `}` are also present in the tree. Any ideas how to solve this problem? Thank you.

```
from lark import Lark

grammar = r"""
    start: object

    object : name "{" feature "}" | name

    feature: (DIGIT|LETTER|"+"|"-"|"*"|"_")+
    name: CNAME

    %import common.LETTER
    %import common.DIGIT
    %import common.CNAME
    %import common.WS
    %ignore WS
"""

parser = Lark(grammar, parser='lalr',
                   lexer='standard',
                   propagate_positions=False,
                   maybe_placeholders=False
                   )
def test():
    test_str = '''
        Apple_3{3+}
    '''

    j = parser.parse(test_str)
    print(j.pretty())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

The output looks like this:

```
start
  object
    name    Apple_3
    feature 3
```

instead of

```
start
  object
    name    Apple_3
    feature 
      3
      +
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you tried placing `!` before special characters. As I understand the question you linked, the `!` has to be replaced before the rule:

```
!feature: (DIGIT|LETTER|"+"|"-"|"*"|"_")+
```

This produces your expected result for me:

```
start
  object
    name    Apple_3
    feature
      3
      +
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The solution you proposed works only in some cases. Once a `LETTER` is present in `feature` expression, an exception is thrown:

e.g. for `test_str = "Apple_3{3+a}"` the following exception
`lark.exceptions.UnexpectedToken: Unexpected token Token(CNAME, 'a')`

Comment: @Matho, his answer is correct. The exception you're getting is because of a collision between `LETTER` and `CNAME`. This is because you're using `lexer="standard"`, which the documentation explicitly states is there only for legacy. So either remove it and use the default lexer, or fix the priority manually.

Comment: @Erez yes you are right, that is something I didn't notice. Sorry and thank you both.